# Как заполнить свойство классами?

Tags: c#, массивы, ооп, классы

ТЗ: Продукты должны храниться в свойстве Products[] класса Store, и должны генерироваться в количестве 20 штук случайным набором из 5 вариантов продукта:

У меня есть класс Store и классы еды

```
    internal class Store
    {
        public DateTime GetRandomDeliveryTime()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomValue = random.Next(1, 201);
            DateTime deliveryTimestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-randomValue);
            return deliveryTimestamp;
        }

        public string GetRandomStoragePlace()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomValue = random.Next(1, 3);
            string storagePlace;
            if (randomValue == 1)
                storagePlace = "Icebox";
            else
                storagePlace = "Showcase";
            return storagePlace;
        }

        public void DoInspection()
        {   

        }
    }

    abstract class Product : Store
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual double StorageLifeDays { get; set; }
        public virtual string StoragePlace { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DeliveryTimestamp { get; set; }

        public abstract bool IsFresh();
    }

    internal class Corn : Product
    {
        public override string Name
        {
            get => base.Name = "Corn";
        }

        public override string StoragePlace
        {
            get => base.StoragePlace = GetRandomStoragePlace();
        }

        public override double StorageLifeDays
        {
            get => base.StorageLifeDays = 150;
        }

        public override DateTime DeliveryTimestamp
        {
            get => base.DeliveryTimestamp = GetRandomDeliveryTime();
        }

        public override bool IsFresh()
        {
            double isFresh = (double)DateTime.Now.Subtract(DeliveryTimestamp).TotalDays;
            if (isFresh <= StorageLifeDays)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

И таких классов продуктов несколько. По тз продукты должны храниться в свойстве Products[] класса Store, и должны генерироваться в количестве 20 штук случайным набором из 5 вариантов продукта. И я не могу понять как заполнить массив Product[]

Comment: Почему у вас "Кукуруза" это "Магазин"?

Comment: О чем вы? Это где?

Comment: В вашем коде) Вот вы пишете `class Corn : Product` (то есть "класс Кукуруза является **наследником** продукта"), далее `Product : Store` (класс Продукт является **наследником** магазина), из чего, по вашей логике, кукуруза == магазин. То есть, вы можете в коде сейчас написать `Store store = new Corn();`. Ну а теперь подумайте, точно "Кукуруза" и даже "Продукт" являются "Магазином", или в вашей логике, структуре, есть некие косяки..?

Comment: Если Продукт не будет наследником Магазина я не смогу обратиться к методам которые прописаны в классе Магазин. Методы string GetRandomStoragePlace() GetRandomDeliveryTime() используются в классе Кукурузы

Comment: ТЗ к задаче может будет яснее https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2180130.html

Comment: А почему вы решили, что "Кукуруза" вообще должна что-либо делать и вообще размещать себя где-либо самостоятельно? Вот просто подумайте логически, есть магазин, у него есть полки, есть сотрудник, который на эти полки положит продукт. Или все же заходит такая кукуруза в магазин, садится на первой попавшейся полке и назначает себе цену, так? По вашей логике да. Вот что должно быть у продукта? Наверно название, да? Цена, вес, размеры, может быть "этикетка" с некими данными магазина, но там же ведь не должно быть методов, которые "поместят кукурузу на полку", это просто не ответственность продукта.

Comment: Получается мне в классах продуктов не стоит использовать методы Магазина?

Comment: Конечно, ибо продукт не должен отвечать за магазин. За размещение товара, его наполнение и прочее - отвечает ведь сам магазин. А то у вас и правда, кукуруза заходит самостоятельно в магазин и садится на полку) Просто думайте логически, не машинно, мол "тут метод, который я должен вызвать", нет! Весь код - это логика, которая легко проецируется на реальный мир. Так что, просто представьте себе реальный магазин и опишите его сначала словами, потом кодом.

Comment: Продукты это абстрактный класс в котором есть поля с названием сроком годности местом где он хранился и датой когда был сделан завоз. Далее есть продукт определенный Кукуруза в котором переопределяются поля абстрактного класса Продукт. но вот в чем дело для того чтобы переопределить поля мне нужны методы с Магазина а их с не могу использовать

Comment: `с Магазина а их с не могу использовать` - наверно потому, что у вас в магазине нету "Продуктов" (которая требуется по заданию), а также магазин не создает те самые продукты, с нужными для него параметрами..? Вот у вас в классе магазина должно быть `public Product[] Products {get; private set;}` (список всех продуктов магазина). Далее, должно быть заполнение магазина, чтот по типу `Products[0] = new Corn("Кукуруза сладкая", "Icebox");` (лучше использовать коллекции (`List<Product>`), также `Icebox` лучше сделать как `enum` или своя абстракция). Ну и вот уже у вас магазин отвечает за наполнение

Comment: хорошо, попробую спасибо. Если что отпишусь что получилось :)